# Is KendoUI a competitor to AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Are AngularJS and KendoUI competing frameworks or are they used to solve different problems?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, very different things.
Angular is a framework for building single page applications. Kendo is a control suite

Comment: Can they be used together? Is this often done? Are there other control suites out there that are used with AngularJS?

Comment: Yes, Kendo can totally be used together with Angular. It is useful if you want to add a Kendo control like a grid or something to your Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Define "competitor".

AngularJS is a framework for building JS applications which doesn't come bundled with UI widgets (but there are projects like [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/)).

Kendo UI provides UI controls like grids, date pickers, charts, but also things like a [router module](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/spa/router), [view models](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview) and [templating](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) for bidirectional data binding. So while they're not equivalent (Kendo UI having a focus on, well, UI, and AngularJS on the framework aspect), there is some overlap.

You can also use them in combination, e.g. by making use of the [Angular Kendo project](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/).